# Using LXML To Return Title Text

Tags: python, lxml

I am working on a school project and I am using LXML and it's .xpath function to try to get the titles for the top videos on a youtube search that you can pick. My problem is when it is iterating through the top 5 and returning the title values of the videos I can't seem how to return the actual title no matter what I do. I have tried to do `/text()` or `/string` or `/title/text()` since the text I am trying to get is in the title but everything I do just returns a blank list `[]`.

Here is my python code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

string = input("Enter what you want to search up on Youtube: \n")
string.replace(" ", "+")
page = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + string)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
for x in range(5):
  v = tree.xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-search/div[1]/ytd-two-column-search-results-renderer/div/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-video-renderer[1]/div[1]/div/div[' + str(x) + ']/div/h3/a')
  print(v)
```

And here is what I am getting returned:

```
Enter what you want to search up on Youtube:
rainbow
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

And this is the HTML of what I am trying to pull the **TITLE TEXT** this from:

```
<a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" title="Hide and Seek in Rainbow Six Siege... Let's Go!!" href="/watch?v=g8MM_RS7zmw" aria-label="Hide and Seek in Rainbow Six Siege... Let's Go!! by Get_Flanked 8 hours ago 21 minutes 54,654 views">
                Hide and Seek in Rainbow Six Siege... Let's Go!!
              </a>
```

Comment: You need to write `string = string.replace(" ", "+")`, otherwise the spaces are not replaced in the original query string. Are you able to find other elements in the page?

Comment: If you inspect the `page.content` or `page.text`, you are actually not gonna see these elements you assume you are getting. The page you download is not the same that you see in your browser in other words.

Comment: Thanks and yes, I was able to get some "Elements (random mem spot)" to return but nothing farther than that but I think if I can get that I should be able to get what I am looking for?

Comment: alecxe so you're saying that the page that I am downloading doesn't include what I am trying to get or its tree is formatted differently??

Comment: Also just wondering if no one answers dose my question just sit here or are most of them usually answered?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the YouTube data api they do have a Python library.

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets?apix=true

Otherwise, if you're looking to use a scraper of some sort, you'll need one that can execute JavaScript. `requests` only downloads the html text file, it doesn't run JavaScript.

For example with Selenium.

```
import selenium.webdriver

options = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=montypython')

[x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]')]
[x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_id('video-title')]
print(dir(driver))

# how to get html tag attributes for example href
x.get_attribute("href")

>>> [x.get_attribute('title') for x in driver.find_elements_by_id('video-title')]
['Monty Python And The Holy Grail 1975 HD', 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail', "Monty Python's - The Funniest Joke in the World (la blague qui tue)", 'Argument', 'Monty Python - The Black Knight - Tis But A Scratch', 'Monty Python- Cheese Shop', 'Monty Python: The Parrot Sketch & The Lumberjack Song movie versions HQ', 'Biggus Dickus - Monty Python, Life of Brian.', 'Monty Python - Bridge of Death', 'Life of Brian 1979 (sub indo)', 'John Cleese - How To Irritate People 1968', 'Monty Python and The Holy Grail - Black Knight HD', 'Eric Idle - "Always Look On The Bright Side Of Life" - STEREO HQ', 'Monty pythons, Mr creosote, Full version,', 'Monty Python   Ministry of Silly Walks NL', 'Monty Python - careers advice', 'Monty Python and the Holy Grail - Bunny Attack Scene (HD)', 'Monty Python Society For Putting Things On Top of Other Things', 'Monty Python - Constitutional Peasants Scene (HD)']
```